# Meaning of aphorism 133 from chapter 4 in beyond good and evil by Nietzsche

Tags: nietzsche, explanation

I have started reading Nietzsche's books and I come across a quote that resonates with me personally as probably with other people and I am curious if someone would like to attempt to further explain the quote or direct me to useful sources.

Beyond Good and Evil, chapter # 4:

> "133. He who cannot find the way to HIS ideal, lives more frivolously and shamelessly than the man without an ideal."

I have also looked into "Nietzsche's Task: An Interpretation of Beyond Good and Evil" and "A Beginner's Guide to Nietzsche's Beyond Good and Evil" but could not find a satisfying answer that explains this specific aphorism.

Here is a question that has been asked in this forum too: ["Interpretation of Nietzsche's aphorisms in Beyond Good And Evil"](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/28772/interpretation-of-nietzsches-aphorisms-in-beyond-good-an-evil)

Comment: My interpretation is something like this: Many people go about professing all kinds of ideals (especially of the "moral" kind that Nietzsche is concerned with) and yet never manage to live according to them. The example I have in mind is the clergy of the pre-medival period. His point is that these hypocrites are in fact less scrupulous than those who are simply "amoral" in some sense. Its as if having the intention to act morally gives license for the complete opposite.

Comment: So, by the virtue of knowledge you are saying that those with "moral/virtue" and not living up to the desired morality are deprived of living a satisfying life compared with the ignorants i.e., a man without virtue.

Comment: why not look at the aphorisms before and after it?

Comment: "the man without an ideal" is like the time when Adam didn't eat the apple from that Tree of good and bad thus without real self-consciousness. After he ate the apple and become conscious of good and bad then you could say he formed his ideal but yet to find the way to achieve. That's why this aphorism appears in a chapter about Good and Evil...

Answer (score 3):

In it's German original it's apparently:

> Wer den Weg zu *seinem* Ideale nicht zu finden weiss, lebt
> leichtsinniger und frecher, als der Mensch ohne Ideale.

Sure "leichtsinnig" could be translated with *frivolous* and "frech" with *shameless* and if you translated one as such the other seems plausible but "leichtsinnig" technically means "easy on your senses"/"lighthearted" so the opposite of "being alert" and more of a *careless* or *reckless* nature and "frech" is more *bold* or *brazen*.

So he might be hinting that people with an ideal but no clear conception of what it means in practice might be more in danger/of a danger to act in reckless self-righteousness than people without an ideal to begin with.

Like how people tend to (ab)use a vague good cause to rationalize doing harm, while someone without a cause (not even the motivation to do good), would need to value their actions as-is.

So someone who is convinced of following the right ideal, but has no clear conception of how to get there is more likely to take risks because they'd hope, assume that they'd pick the right path. Thereby acting careless and brazen?

But that's just guesswork the nature of aphorisms is that they usually have no supporting context so it's either self-evident or whatever you make out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think someone else mentioned this also, but my interpretation is why chase something that only leads to disappointment when you cannot reach that goal. Like in Buddhism, they don't believe in the concept of 'Chasing happiness' as this only leads to you being unhappy. In addition, by living shamelessly I guess he is getting at the idea that if to avoid that disappointment of not reaching your goal, man will do anything to get to it no matter who or what that might hurt - touching upon the will to power.

Instead, having no goals, but becoming more open minded, not believing in set truths, and allowing change to happen and take it as it comes is a better way in which to live.

Buut like others have also mentioned here, Nietszche is more than capable of shutting his own thoughts down in other comments - but I would argue that is philosophy, and they show his thoughts and process to getting to his final answer

Comment: Nietzsche hates buddhism. It is the opposite : you need to chase what you will to do, not doing it because of morals or philosophy, is acting against the nature of life, and the sign of a strong instinct desorder --> cf. his critique of Socrate.

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb here, but considering the emphasis on "HIS" and Nietzsche definition of the ubermensh as someone who can define and follow through with their own morals and ideas,  as opposed to someone who caves in and follows morals imposed upon them by social pressure, I think the idea is "someone who follows ideals that are not their own, that were imposed upon them, is more despicable than one who has no ideals at all".

It seems logical: one as either (1) no ideals, or (2) ideals from someone else, or (3) their own ideals.

In Nietzsche's view, 3 is the ubermensh. The aphorism seems to indicate that, while 1 and 2 are both untermensh, 1 is still better than 2.